# Android Firebase code organization (concept)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, code-organization

I'm developing my first android app using Firebase. It is also my first android app overall, so I'm not expirienced, but already got some expirience with programming lanugages such as Java or PHP. I'm searching for professional advice since I've run into some problems with my code organization. I already did some research but was not able to find a good solution for this.

My app uses Firebase Authentication and Firebase Realtime Database.

I'm going to explain all relevant parts for my problem.

---

**The main activity...**

- Checks if a user is logged in, if not, start the authentication activity
- Contains a Object `DatabaseHandler`, which is responsible for the database access, this object needs a [UserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserInfo) object to be instantiated
- Contains a `FirebaseAuth` object attached with a `AuthStateListener`
- This `AuthStateListener` check if a user is logged in, if so it will re-instantiate the `DatabaseHandler` object with the current user
- Should be able to display some data retrieved from the `DatabaseHandler`

---

**My problem**

I already need to have access to the `DatabaseHandler` object in the `onCreate()` method of the `MainActivity` to display some data, but since the `DatabaseHandler` gets instantiated in the method `onAuthStateChanged()`, to make sure there is already a user logged in, this does not work, because `onCreate()` is called before `onAuthStateChanged()`

---

**My thoughts**

I'm not entirely sure how to solve this problem, but my first thought was to restructure my project in a way that my main activity only checks which activities to call, instead of displaying data on it's own. I'm still in the early phase of the project, so this should not be much of a problem.
Just wanted to know if this will work or if there is any better solution to this.

Let me know what you think

Comment: As far as I understand, you do not **have** to get and display your data in `onCreate`. You can update the UI from another custom method in your activity. You will need to either 'find' the UI Elements in this method then, or declare them as fields of your Activity class and 'find' them in `onCreate`. I can post an example of what I mean if you want to.

Comment: As said I'm not that familiar with android concepts. I'm using a recylcer view, mostly got that code from a tutorial and as of this tutorial I have to declare content of the recylcerview in the `onCreate()` method

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of the activity with code that assumes you want to display a List of Books:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private BookAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        adapter = new BookAdapter(bookList);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            // User is still logged in
            // Get UserInfo and instantiate DatabaseHandler
            populateList();
        } else {
            // No user is logged in, go to auth activity
        }
    }

    private void populateList() {
        // Get Books from Firebase and add them to the adapter
        Book book = new Book();
        bookList.add(book);

        // Notify the adapter, so that it updates the UI
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

With this you do the following:

- create and instantiate all objects in `onCreate`
- check for user in `onCreate` and act accordingly
- get Data and display it from `populateList`, which allows to re-populate the list without going through all of the `onCreate` stuff (remember to `clear` the list/adapter

Comment: This looks promising. I'm going to review this in detail when I'm back to my PC.

Comment: @IanFako hey Ian, any progress with this? Did my answer help you?